# How to calculate duration of timestamp when only given start_time and the end_time is the next row in start_time using PL SQL?

Tags: time, plsql, timestamp, duration

I have this data where I need to calculate the duration of end_time - start_time, but I am only given the start_time and the end_time would be the next row in start_time. How can I do the select statement to get the end_time using PL SQL?

Current Table Example:

[image: Current Table Example]

Expected Table:

[image: Expected Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `lead` analytic function which returns the *next* date value (sorted by `start_time`); then subtract `end - start` to get duration which is measured in number of days (as that's what you get when you subtract two `date` datatype values). If you want, you can format it so that it looks prettier.

Setting date format (so that we'd know *what is what*):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (product, start_time) as
  2    (select 'A', to_date('01.07.2023 12:25:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  3     select 'B', to_date('01.07.2023 12:29:35', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  4     select 'C', to_date('01.07.2023 12:32:02', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
  5    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  6  select
  7    product,
  8    start_time,
  9    nvl(lead(start_time) over (order by start_time), start_time) as end_time,
 10    --
 11    nvl(lead(start_time) over (order by start_time), start_time) - start_time as duration_in_days
 12  from test
 13  order by start_Time;

PRODUCT  START_TIME          END_TIME            DURATION_IN_DAYS
-------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------------
A        01.07.2023 12:25:30 01.07.2023 12:29:35       ,002835648
B        01.07.2023 12:29:35 01.07.2023 12:32:02       ,001701389
C        01.07.2023 12:32:02 01.07.2023 12:32:02                0

SQL>
```